# How to store the contents of the clipboard into a variable?

Tags: vbscript

I want to put into a variable, the text content of the clipboard !
I can paste, but not copy !
So, my question is : ***How to store the contents of the clipboard into a variable ?***

```
' Set what you want to put in the clipboard '
strMessage = "Hello World"
' Declare an object for the word application '
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

' Using the object '
With objWord
   .Visible = False             ' Don't show word '
   .Documents.Add               ' Create a document '
   .Selection.TypeText strMessage   ' Put text into it '
   .Selection.WholeStory        ' Select everything in the doc '
   .Selection.Copy              ' Copy contents to clipboard '
   .Quit False                  ' Close Word, don't save ' 
End With
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use clipboard from VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/128463/692942)

Comment: Looks to me like you knew about these duplicates anyway, your question code is taken directly from this answer - [A: Use clipboard from VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/140800/692942). The answer only mentions *"put your data onto the clipboard"* you'd be better trying one of the others like [this one that creates a class to leverage different methods to send and retrieve data from the clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8565085/692942) or [The easiest way is to use built-in mshta.exe functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36991258/692942)